# How to log prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React, it's only my first day in class.
All i'm trying to do, is when i click a box log the color prop.

I know i cant do console.log(this.props.color)
because this is referencing App...
this is all so confusing right now..any tips would be appreciated.

```
class Boxes extends Component{
  render(props){
    return (
      <div className="boxes" onClick={this.props.getBoxColor}>
        <div className="box1" color="red"></div>
        <div className="box2" color="orange"></div>
        <div className="box3" color="yellow"></div>
        <div className="box4" color="green"></div>
        <div className="box5" color="blue"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {

  getBoxColor=()=>{
    console.log(this.props)
  }


  render() {
    return (
    <Boxes classColor={this.color} getBoxColor={this.getBoxColor} />
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You are calling `App` without any props, so it will return empty. Also, you are using wrong names. You are sending `getBoxClassName` to `Boxes` but trying to access `getBoxColor`

Comment: Should I somehow pass the Boxes component to App

Comment: a few more days of learning and im cringing very hard about this post lol

Answer (score 2):

Try this, tell me if it works for you.

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const className = this.props.className;
    const color = this.props.color;
    return (
      <div
        className={className}
        color={color}
        onClick={() => console.log(color)}
      />
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Box className="box1" color="red" />
        <Box className="box2" color="blue" />
        <Box className="box3" color="green" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: This answer is good, but I think it would help OP a lot by explaining your changes. for example: why put onClick on each element instead of handling event bubbling + capturing target data, why it's important to make sure the prop names match (instead of the mismatched function prop names in the example)

Comment: He has put `onclick` on each element to get the information of each element.In the code you have provided in the question. The `onclick` function is firing off when the div with 'boxes' class is clicked and it calls the `getBoxColor` of the app component. The `getBoxColor` is console logging the props of the app component and is not getting any information as to what box is being clicked.